# Menu CSS is not accessible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The recent (last ~36 hours?) changes to some of the CSS has had a detrimental impact on the accessibility of the site.

The seclected menu option is now *almost* completely indistinguishable from the background. See `/questions` below (in the bottom image, `/tags` is being hovered):

[image]

The menu on the main site is working correctly with the selected item the same colour as the hovered element.

Comment: I didn't look as far as you did, but it seemed like some of the fonts changed in the footer as well.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, the "Would you like to have responses to your questions emailed?" is now a large monofont, but that has no real impact on accessability...

Comment: The fonts on post notices also seem to involve monospace fonts in an ugly way. I thought that was just me being on Windows.

Comment: @muru something changed around ~36 hours ago. I assumed they were just experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This will be fixed with the next production build.